# How to resolve error On List collection it's can't accept or execut ToList() method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Web;  
using System.Web.Mvc; 
using MahadevBhaktDB; 
using MahadevBhaktModal; 
namespace MahadevBhakt_Dewasi_.Controllers
{   
 public class AdminController : Controller
  {
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       return View();
    }
   public List<Tab_Country> GetCountryList()     
   {
     DSPDatabaseEntities db = new  DSPDatabaseEntities(); 
     List<Tab Country>  tab_Countries = db.tab_Countries.Tolist(); 
     return tab_Countries;
    }
   }   
}
```

'object' does not contain a definition for   'ToList' and no accessible extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument  of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) .

This kind of error is come and  but i try to import some packages but there is not available so how to pick that kinds of package in my project.

Comment: Can you try adding `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Yes already try.

Comment: OH! `ToList()`, not `Tolist()`. And please keep the `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Still is not working!

Comment: Please post your class source fully.